# Ignore special characters in comparison in shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, special-characters

In my script I am comparing the temp variable and if it is blank I want to update the temp variable. But the below script is not working.

**Script:**

```
temp=`head -5 $filename1 | tail -1`
if [ "$temp" == " " ]
then
    temp=`head -6 $filename1 | tail -1`
    echo "Blank - Updated temp value"
else
    echo "$temp not blank"
fi
```

Upon troubleshooting I found this when I used the `od` command. When I checked the temp variable it has special characters because of that its not considering it has blank.

```
echo $temp | od -c
0000000  \r  \n
0000002
```

Can you help on how to ignore the above special characters?

Comment: To strip the carriage return and newline from the output, you might `temp=$(head -5 $filename | tail -1 | tr -d '\r\n')`

Comment: Pre-process with dos2unix to fix that and potentially other idiosyncrasies of Microsoft text formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:

```
if [ "$temp" == " " ]
```

The comparison operator is actually `=`, not `==`. The latter works in some shells, but isn't standard. Also, you're comparing the variable not against an empty string, but one containing a single space, which may or may not be what your file has.

If the file can contain extra whitespace, it might be a good idea to just remove all of it with `sed` or `tr`. And then you can just use `[ -z "$temp" ]` to test if it's empty. So:

```
temp=$(head -5 $filename | tail -1 | tr -d ' \t\r')
if [ -z "$temp" ] ; then ...
```

Instead of `head` and `tail`, you can use `sed` to pick a single line:

```
temp=$(sed -n '5p' | tr -d ' \t\r')
if [ -z "$temp" ] ; then ...
```

(`5p` means "on line 5, (p)rint the line", and `-n` inhibits the default action of printing any lines.)

---

Actually, instead of the test I'm a bit tempted to just go through the file with an `awk` script to get the fifth or sixth line depending on if the fifth has anything:

```
temp=$(tr -d ' \t\r' < $filename1 | awk '(NR==5 && $0) || NR==6 {print; exit}' )
```

(`NR==5` tests the current line (record) number, `$0` expands to the contents of the line, and is "true" if the line is not empty, `&&` and `||` are the usual *and* and *or* operations)

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and removing all whitespace characters...
`temp=$(head -5 $filename1 | tail -1 | sed -r 's/\s+//g')`